# Shape is not returned for some HERE Geocoder API requests

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I use the following URL to fetch Shape of postal code in Italy:
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?postalCode=08013&country=Italy&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode

Actually, this URL works fine for almost all postal (e.g. 08012) codes.

However, there are a few (e.g. 08013) where the location is defined but Shape property is absent:
`{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2020-01-29T15:40:52.032+0000"},"View":[{"_type":"SearchResultsViewType","ViewId":0,"Result":[{"Relevance":1.0,"MatchLevel":"postalCode","MatchQuality":{"Country":1.0,"PostalCode":1.0},"Location":{"LocationId":"NT_CWJpjOLnf1bC2mdwnAMVkA","LocationType":"area","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":40.33425,"Longitude":8.49083},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":40.33425,"Longitude":8.49083}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":40.4079,"Longitude":8.40124},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":40.26122,"Longitude":8.56773}},"Address":{"Label":"08013, Bosa, Sardegna, Italia","Country":"ITA","State":"Sardegna","County":"OR","City":"Bosa","PostalCode":"08013","AdditionalData":[{"value":"Italia","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Sardegna","key":"StateName"},{"value":"Oristano","key":"CountyName"}]}}}]}]}}`

When I change `additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode` to `city` or `country` it returns Shape but obviously this shape is not of postal code which I need.

The question is whether HERE Geocoder API has some gaps of data or this can be somehow overcame?

Answer (score 0):

For some zone shape level supports `additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,city/country` **city** or **country** only because not all the zones have shape attribute.

Comment: Hmm, sad news. Looks like it makes impossible to use the API for this purpose when from 4500 zip codes in Italy 100 are absent. No workaround with HERE Geocoder API?

Comment: Do you have plans to complete the data in not far future?